# 500 Internal Server Error using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I am getting 500 internal server error into firebug.This code is working nice on localhost.Please help me.This is my code.I am uploading file and that's why i have used action also into  tag.

```
<script src="js/jquery.form.js"></script> 
<script src="js/create_input.js"></script>
<script> 
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        $('#UploadForm').on('submit', function(e) { 
            e.preventDefault();
                            var value= $("#valS").val();
                            var host=$('#host').val(); alert(host);
            $(this).ajaxSubmit({
                type: "POST",
                url: host+"views/excel_import.php",
                data: {value: value},
                target: '#Exceloutput',
                success:  afterMsg //call function after success
            });  
        });
    }); 

    function afterMsg(msg)  { 

        $("#Exceloutput").html(msg);

    } 


</script> 

<form action="http://localhost/shop/admin/views/excel_import.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="UploadExcel" class="form has-validation">

  <div class="clearfix">
           <label for="form-upload" class="form-label">Upload File<em>*</em></label>
           <div class="form-input">
               <input type="file" size="50" class="text" id="excelfile" name="excelfile" required="required"/>
               <input type="hidden" size="50" class="text" id="valS" name="valS" value="1" required="required"/>
           </div>
  </div>

 <div class="form-action clearfix">
         <button class="button class-button" type="submit" id="SubmitButton">Upload</button>
         <button class="button class-button" type="submit" id="updatefields" name="updatefields">UpdateExcel</button>
 </div>
```

Comment: "500 Internal Server Error" means that an error has occurred on the server. You'd rather be investigating the error details on the server side.

Comment: -1. Not enough information.

Comment: On server in my error log file it is showing error message : HTTP request length 138444 (so far) exceeds MaxRequestLen (131072). Anyone have idea?

Comment: The error message is pretty clear: The server has a limit somewhere that the transmitted data may not exceed 131072 bytes. But your request seems to be bigger. So you need to increase the limit on the server side.

Comment: but there is no php.ini file on server where i need to change it?

Comment: Start a new question with a complete description of this error including all details about the server (OS, web server, PHP setup) and just minimal details of the client side.

Comment: A bit of google shows me [this](http://www.howtoforge.com/apache2-mod_fcgid-http-request-length-exceeds-maxrequestlen)

Comment: I'd rather decrease the request size on the client side if you have no chance to increase the allowed size on server side. What is inside `{value: value}` ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see quite a few variables being defined.

host?

```
url: host+"views/excel_file_import.php",
```

value?

```
data: {value: value},
```

are there any errors in your console aside from the 500?  It sounds like it might be something wrong with your script.  what is the relevant code in *excel_file_import.php*, in particular the part that is dealing with the POST params...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using this code on your server, the url is pointing to localhost, which would probably be in error, on top of that a cross-site browser restriction issue as well.

Serverside 500 errors, first thing I do is check the webservers error log, or php-cgi error log respectively.

After [googling](http://www.faqforge.com/linux/fix-http-request-length-134926-so-far-exceeds-maxrequestlen-error-on-debian-linux/) a bit, this [looks a lot like your error](http://www.howtoforge.com/apache2-mod_fcgid-http-request-length-exceeds-maxrequestlen) message:

Set:

```
FcgidMaxRequestLen 2000000

which equals roughly 2 MB.

The default value is

FcgidMaxRequestLen 131072
```

So, change that value.  Your POST size is exceeding the upload limit.

Comment: Yes in error log file i have checked and it is showing error--> HTTP request length 138444 (so far) exceeds MaxRequestLen (131072). where i need to change for it?

Comment: Aha. Interesting.  You are hitting a http url length limit .... change to the POST method.   You have to examine your headers now with firebug as you are sending a huge one

Comment: Pretty good point ....  Perhaps it's combining the method.  It's possible to use POST/GET together.  I think he needs to examine the request headers in his client now.

Answer (score 0):

From the provided error message I guess that you are using mod_fcgid so you should edit the file:

```
/etc/apache2/mods-available/fcgid.conf
```

and add (or change) the value of MaxRequestLen to a bigger number.
The filepath is the default for the mode_fcgi but it might be different if you have any control panel (cpanel, parallels) where you might need to edit your vhost fcgid.